# Android Studio - Compatibility settings greyed out in Windows 7 64

Tags: android-studio

I am running Android Studio under Windows 7 64 bit, with a DPI scaling setted up at 150%. The text is of course blurred, and the only thing I could do is to "Disable display scaling on high DPI settings" from the program's properties/compatibility tab: the problem is that the settings are grayed out.
Anybody knows what the problem could be?
Thank you in advance

(I would have added the screenshot but my rank is too low, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem in the following way.

I am not sure about whether it has caveats, but it's really simple. The settings are greyed out because it's a) a 64-bit application or b) a part of 64-bit Windows distribution

**Solution is to use a 32-bit shell with high-DPI disabled to start a 64-bit program.** I'm not sure whether it has memory addressing implications, but it should work for any application.

Good candidates are 32-bit versions of *bash*, or anything else you can find.